# Unhandled Exception: RangeError: Value not in range: 22

Tags: flutter, dart

I am receiving the following error when the image is not set for the user:

"Unhandled Exception: RangeError: Value not in range: 22"

when the photo is set, everything comes right

My code:

```
Future<Map> getData() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (prefs != null) {
      var photo = ((prefs.getString('photo') ?? ""));
      print('photo');
      print(photo);
      String image = "";
      if (image != null && image != "") {
        image = photo.substring(22);
      }
    } else {
      print('usu error');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per error, If `photo` is an empty string then using `substring(22)` on `photo` will throw the exception so add another check `photo.length > 22` to verify the lenth before substring as:

```
 if (image != null && image != "" && photo.length > 22) {
```

The `image` is always empty as `image` is being declared and initialised right before `if` so you can modify `if` condition as:

```
if (prefs != null) {
      var photo = ((prefs.getString('photo') ?? ""));
      print('photo');
      print(photo);
      String image = "";
      if (photo.length > 22) {
        image = photo.substring(22);
      }
    } else {
      print('usu error');
    }
```